# Using a git repo on a directory shared between a VM and a host causes problems

Tags: git, github, virtualbox, shared-directory

I have an ubuntu VM on an osx host.  I have a shared drive from the host with a git clone of a project from github.   I would like to be able to perform git commands both on the host and the guest, on the same shared directory

I primarily edit and commit from the osx host and primarily compile and run from the ubuntu guest, which works fine.   But occasionally I would like to run a git command from the guest.

This causes problems though.   If I run `git status` on the ubuntu host, git acts like all of the files are untracked.

I did a git clone on a separate dir on the host and compared .git/config between that and the .git/config on the shared drive and they are the same.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Having multiple users in a single repository, whether they're different actual human users, or the same human on multiple machines using a shared file system location, is not the way `git` is designed to run. File system caching at the very least will cause problems in this situation. Better to clone a second copy and set up to push/fetch between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found if I umounted the share and remounted it with the same UID/GID as my mac user it works.   First I [changed my UID on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id) to match my user on mac, then I mounted it with:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf myshare /media/sf_myshare/ -o rw,uid=501,gid=20
```

git is now happy.